# Flutter: Access variable declared and defined in _Widgetstatefulstate from Statefulwidget

Tags: flutter, variables, statefulwidget

I need to access a variable declared and defined in the state of my stateful widget:

```
class StatItemDeclarable extends StatefulWidget {
  const StatItemDeclarable({Key? key, required this.title, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final int index;
  
  //Need to access variables here


  @override
  State<StatItemDeclarable> createState() => _StatItemDeclarableState(title: title, index: index);
}

class _StatItemDeclarableState extends State<StatItemDeclarable> {

  _StatItemDeclarableState({required this.title, required this.index});

  String title; // Variable to access
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final int index;
  bool deleted = false;
  late Color _color; // Variable to access
```

I'm quite new to flutter so I would appreciate some help :)

The variables I wanted to access were not accessable in the StatefulWidget

Comment: The state class have access to stateful widget class but not the other way around. It would be great if you could tell us why do you need to access those variable in Stateful class?

Answer (score -1):

you can access to these variables just by using  widget. like this:

```
widget.title;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mohammad, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work somehow:

class StatItemDeclarable extends StatefulWidget {
  const StatItemDeclarable({Key? key, required this.title, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final int index;

  //Need to access variables here
  String someTitle = widget.title;


  @override
  State<StatItemDeclarable> createState() => _StatItemDeclarableState(title: title, index: index);
}

error:
Undefined name 'widget'.

Answer (score -2):

you can access any var declared in constructer by used keyword widget before variable name like  this:

```
widget.title;
widget.index;
```